# $(...).modal is not a function Booststrap 3 & Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to add a modal to my page using Bootstrap's modal, but the following code gives this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`. I want the modal to show up when the user arrives on the page. (Notice that if I add a button that triggers the modal, it works But this isn't what I want)

application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
//= require owlcarousel2/owl.carousel
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

index.html.erb

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed this step. You will have to rename app/assets/stylesheets/application.css to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass. Then we can import the Bootstrap assets in your newly-renamed application.css.sass file.

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass

...

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

and also use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
})
```

Comment: Bootstrap actually works, it is just the manually-written JS part that doesn't. I have an application.scss file where I import boostsrap and booststrap-sprockets. It should do the job, right ?

Comment: $(…).modal is defined in bootstrap.min.js check if it is loaded or not in network.

Comment: Could not find what the problem was; I finally designed my modal box without bootstrap